# Why is a just created file not found?

Tags: vba, excel

I have

> error 53 'file not found'

Here is the most streamlined version of the script:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim NJ As String, path As String, Oud As String, Archief As String, Nieuw As String
    
    path = "C:\Test" & "\"
    
    Oud = path & "A"
    Archief = path & ("Archive") & "\" & "A"
    Nieuw = path & "B"
    
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Oud
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Archief
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Nieuw
    Kill Oud
    
End Sub
```

I tried to bypass the possibility of a too-long pathname by limiting it to its bare essentials.
I created a new file, which I gave a variable name to make sure no mistakes were made in the pathname.
I spoke with IT to make sure I have proper permissions to change, edit and delete files.

The script does not make a lot of sense, (why not just create Archief and Nieuw?), but I am trying to understand the error that occurs in another script in which I try to archive some files (say, "name 2017") in an archive folder, rename them for the new year in the original file (e.g. "name 2018") and then kill the original 2017 files to clean up the mess.

It does not make sense that the file I just created cannot be found.

Comment: I assume the error is occurring on the line saying `Kill Oud`, which is effectively `Kill "C:\Test\A"`.  Does the file `"C:\Test\A"` exist?  Because Excel would have saved the workbook as `"C:\Test\A.xlsx"`, `"C:\Test\Archive\A.xlsx"` and `"C:\Test\B.xlsx"`.

Comment: Or maybe `"C:\Test\A.xls"` or `"C:\Test\A.xlsm"` - depending on your default.

Comment: After you `.Saveas Oud`, insert a line like so: `Oud = Activeworkbook.Fullname` - this will set `Oud` to be the actual filename, rather than your shortened version.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` which *might* offer a better solution to your process generally.

Comment: Adding the extensions did not work, but... setting Oud = Activeworkbook.Fullname seems to have done the trick! Now I'm going to try this in my original problem ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the below changes:

1) add these lines to your Code:

```
Dim filename As String

filename = "test.xls" 'You can select any name and any excel file format
```

2) Replace these lines:

```
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Oud
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Archief
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Nieuw
    Kill Oud
```

With these:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Oud & "\" & filename
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Archief & "\" & filename
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Nieuw & "\" & filename

    Kill Oud & "\" & filename
```